# Fix AMP stylesheet error

Tags: amp-html

I'm getting error in [AMP Validator](https://validator.ampproject.org) for my stylesheet's

> The attribute 'href' in tag 'link rel=stylesheet for fonts' is set to
>   the invalid value 'http://domain.cooooom/css/style.css'. Learn
>   more.

I have searched about it and reached to t[his article](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/converting/resolving-errors) from official AMP website.

[image: screen 1]

This is `the most ridiculous` suggestion I've ever seen during all these years of my work.

> They suggest I move all my external CSS files codes to my app head
>   part directly and put them in `<style amp-custom>` tag! so i will have
>   a long & messy head tag just because they can't follow HTML5
>   standards.

## Question

Is there anyway I avoid doing this messy job and validate my file?

Comment: custom css have 50k limil,  Visit this url will help you https://www.ampstart.com/howitworks

Comment: "just because they can't follow HTML5 standards" — If you want to write HTML 5, why are you writing AMP? And it isn't because they couldn't use external stylesheets, it is because AMP is designed to optimise initial load times, and that means minimising the number of HTTP requests.

Comment: @quentin the thing is in real life websites there always additional css files such as bootstrap,owl slide etc. is not just about you shape a box or changing color of text&amp;#39;s obviously there is more than 50k and wether you like or not you have to include some css files, so it really doesn&amp;#39;t make sense to inline all of those in your header just like that. they could just force you to use minified files for loading time instead of forcing you to have them directly in header.

Comment: @mafortis — You continue to miss the point of AMP (which is designed for **simple** and **highly performance optimised** sites and not sites covered in bells and whistles). If you want to build an HTML 5 website, then build an HTML 5 website and not an AMP website. (A minimised file would still have the overhead of an additional HTTP request.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is how AMP works.
You must insert your CSS inline in HTML to save an additional Network. @import is also forbidden.

And the best way is to create a AMP own css Style not put in all your css style from the non-AMP Site.
TIPP: you can insert up to 50KByte CSS but a good work is to keep under 14K ;-)